# Бутстрап разрывает блоки при двухколоночной вёрстке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

Хочу сделать следующий макет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, поскольку блок 3 достаточно высокий, а блок 1 достаточно узкий получается следующий вид с "дыркой" между блоком 1 и 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно избавиться от "дырки" чтобы 1, 2 и 4 шли в одном столбце без разрывов?

Моя заготовка, на которой я тестировал:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm col-md-8">
            <p class="bg-success">a1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
           <p class="bg-primary">b1<br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm col-md-8">
           <p class="bg-danger">c1</p>
           <p class="bg-warning">c2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается очень просто с помощью flex- элементов, добавьте в ваш css  следующий код

```
  .col-md-8{
     display:flex;
     flex-direction:column;
   }

  .col-md-8 p{
     flex:1;
  }
```